# How do I retrieve a json object from a controller method using Jquery and ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm currently trying to call a controller method that returns data in the form of a json object like so:

```
var url = "/campaigns/new_pair.json?id="+campaign_id+'&loser_id='+loser_id+'&winner_id='+winner_id;

        $.getJSON(url, function(){
           alert("success")
        })
        .done(function(data) {
           $pair.data('data', data);
        });
```

Then, when I try to access that data I get the error "Cannot read property 'left_outfit' of undefined "

```
$pair.children(".vote-left").attr("data-votes",$pair.data('data').left_outfit.total_votes);
```

When running this code the success alert does fire, also if I navigate to my url it returns:

```
{"left_outfit":{"outfit_id":1713,"c_outfit_id":1886,"liked":false,"image":"xxx","total_votes":26,"stylist":{"id":41,"image":"xxx","first_name":"xxx"}},"right_outfit":{"outfit_id":1187,"c_outfit_id":1191,"liked":false,"image":"xxx","total_votes":30,"stylist":{"id":53,"image":"xxx","first_name":"xxx"}}}
```

Is this maybe malformed?

Thanks in advance for any input.

EDIT:

$pair gets defined in this way:

```
Pairs.prototype = {

    // init
    _init: function () {
      var $pairs = $('body.open-lookbook-list > section > article'),
        self = this;

      $pairs.each(function (index, pair) {
        var $pair = $(pair);
        self._listeners($pair);
      });
    }
```

...

btw, this is using underscore.js, also the backend is being done with Rails.

Comment: Where is your call to `$pair.children` relative to `.done`?

Comment: can you post what is `$pair`?

Comment: Updated w. more info. The call to $pair.children is done on the next line following the .done block

Comment: @xxyyxx it should not be "***following the .done block***". It should be **inside** the `.done` callback, as that is an AJAX call and so will complete later in time (*after the lines following the block are executed*)..

Answer (score 1):

It's still a bit of a wild guess here, but here's what I should try:

```
var $children = $pair.children(".vote-left");
$children.attr("data-votes", data.left_outfit.total_votes);
```

Since you receive the JSON with the name data, $pair.data('data').left_outfit does not make much sense to me. Instead data.left_outfit.total_votes does.

Updated:

You should be able to retrieve the data you want, by combining your done function with the success function within getJson:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $pair.data('data', data);
});
```

Comment: I've updated my post w. more info, I hope that helps. And yes, I'm trying to store the value in $pair.data('data').left_outfit.total_votes in another data attribute of $pair.

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. It actually turned out that the var I was saving the data object to was not able to be accessed outside of the done block, so that was causing the issue. I ended up saving each bit of information I needed from the json object to some variables I initialized before $.getJSON, and that allowed me to do what I want.